# How to add/subtract two ctypes.c_double in Python

Tags: python, double, ctypes, addition, subtraction

Simple question.  I have two `ctypes.c_double`.  **I would like to add or subtract them together.**

I want to be able to say something like this:

```
In [1]: c_double(2) + c_double(2)
Out[1]: c_double(4.0)
```

Currently, when I try this I get an error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'c_double' and 'c_double'`

My current workaround is this:

```
In [1]: result = c_double(2).value + c_double(2).value

In [2]: c_double(result)
Out[2]: c_double(4.0)
```

Is there a way to directly add/subtract `ctypes.cdouble`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could inherit the `c_double` class to add a `__add__` method

```
import ctypes

class my_c_double(ctypes.c_double):
    def __add__(self,other):
        return my_c_double(self.value + other.value)


a = my_c_double(10)
b = my_c_double(20)

print((a+b).value)
```

prints `30`

Note that you may want to implement `__radd__` and `__iadd__` and check types to be able to directly left add with floats and integers.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a class created by someone else, and it seems that he hasn't written a `__add__` method, that handle the '+' operations.

I would suggest you write you're own method :

```
def add(self, other):
    return c_double(self.value + other.value)
```

Then you tell the `c_double` class that `add` is its `__add__` method:

```
c_double.__add__ = add
```

I think it should work

Comment: and it works. You just have to do `c_double.__add__ = add` in each module where you need addition.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre would you do this in each module's global scope, after `from ctypes import c_double`?